# Pure fixed length queue

Tags: haskell, unit-testing, queue

I am modeling an infectious disease with a fixed incubation period. I chose a queue to keep track of when people become symptomatic. I imagined using some operations like so:

```
queue' = enqueue numberOfPeopleWhoJustGotInfected queue
(numberOfPeopleWhoJustBecameSymptomatic,queue'') = dequeue queue
```

Since `enqueue` and `dequeue` would always be atomic and the queue length would be fixed, I wrote a fixed length queue data structure. `endequeue` models the atomic `enqueue` & `dequeue` sequence. I hope that it will be more efficient than the library [**`Data.Queue`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/queue-0.1.2/docs/Data-Queue.html).

**I'd like feedback on:**

- *Efficiency*. Can it be improved?
- *Typeclasses*. Did I use them correctly? Am I missing others which are applicable?
- *Test Cases*. Are there other logical properties I could add?

**Haskell Code:**

```
module FixedLengthQueue
 ( endequeue
 , fromList
 , length
 , peek
 ) where

import Prelude hiding (foldl,foldl1,foldr,foldr1,length)
import Control.Applicative ((<$>),(<*>))
import Data.Array
import Data.Foldable
import Data.Functor
import Data.Maybe  (fromJust)
import Data.Monoid

type Pointer = Int
type Length  = Int

data FixedLengthQueue a = FLQ Length Pointer (Array Int a)
  deriving (Eq) -- I need to manually define, see tests

instance (Show a) => Show (FixedLengthQueue a) where
  show = ("fromList "++) . show . toList

instance Functor FixedLengthQueue where
  fmap f =  fromJust . fromList . fmap f . toList

instance Foldable FixedLengthQueue where
  foldMap f (FLQ n p arr)
    =  f (arr ! p) <> g (succMod p n)
    where
      g z
        | z /= p    = f (arr ! z) <> g (succMod z n)
        | otherwise = mempty

fromList :: [a] -> Maybe (FixedLengthQueue a)
fromList [] = Nothing -- Nonsensical empty fixed length queue
fromList xs
  = Just
  . FLQ len 0
  . array (0, len-1)
  $ zip   [0..len-1] xs
  where
    len = foldl' inc 0 xs
    inc = flip (const succ)   

length :: FixedLengthQueue a -> Int
length (FLQ n _ _) = n

peek :: FixedLengthQueue a -> a
peek (FLQ _ p arr) = arr ! p

endequeue :: a -> FixedLengthQueue a -> (a,FixedLengthQueue a)
endequeue e (FLQ n p arr)
  = ( arr ! p
    , FLQ n (succMod p n) $ arr // [(p,e)]
    )

succMod n m
  | n' >= m   = n' - m
  | otherwise = n'
  where n' = succ n
```

**Basic Tests:**

```
module Main where

import Prelude hiding (mapM_)
import Data.Foldable
import FixedLengthQueue
import Test.QuickCheck
import Safe

main ::  IO ()
main =   
  mapM_ quickCheck              
  ([ \x -> fmap peek                                        (fromList x) == headMay x
   , \x -> fmap (fst . endequeue undefined)                 (fromList x) == headMay x
   , \x -> fmap (init . toList . snd . endequeue undefined) (fromList x) == tailMay x
   , \x -> let mxs = (replicate 2) <$> (headMay x) >>= fromList
           in (snd . (endequeue <$> peek <*> id) <$> mxs)                == mxs
   ] :: [[Int] -> Bool])
```

Comment: I've found using record syntax in the beginning to be helpful. That way, if you ever change any part of your type,  you don't have to go through and change all of your pattern matching as well.

Comment: @Carcigenicate That's a very good idea

Comment: It usually is. The downside being, if you don't end up changing anything, your code is bloated to deal with records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `fmap` function is overly complicated. `Array x` is a `Functor` and `Length` and `Pointer` are obviously preserved by `fmap`, so:

```
instance Functor FixedLengthQueue where
  fmap f (FLQ a b x) =  FLQ a b $ fmap f x
```

There is `listArray :: Ix i => (i, i) -> [e] -> Array i e`, so you don't need zipping.

`foldl' inc 0 xs` is just `length xs`:

```
fromList :: [a] -> Maybe (FixedLengthQueue a)
fromList [] = Nothing -- Nonsensical empty fixed length queue
fromList xs
  = Just
  . FLQ len 0
  . listArray (0, len-1)
  $ xs
  where
    len = Prelude.length xs
```

Note the qualified use of `Prelude.length`. You can use

```
import Prelude hiding (foldl,foldl1,foldr,foldr1); 
import qualified Prelude (length)
```

if you want `length` to always mean `FixedLenghtQueue.length`. `Prelude.length` will still be available.

Since all your internal arrays are 0-based, there is no need to store `Length` separately, it can be always retrieved by `snd . bounds` or `rangeSize . bounds`

Your `FixedLengthQueue` can be thought as a special array or a special list. So you can just construct the list or the array explicitly and use existing `foldMap` implementations. Here is code using `innerArray` approach:

```
instance Foldable FixedLengthQueue where
    foldMap f = foldMap f . innerArray where
        innerArray (FLQ l p a) = ixmap (bounds a) (mapIdx l p) a
        mapIdx l p i = (i + l - p) `mod` l
```

As for performance, you should benchmark your full application before optimization. Compositional style is not necessary worse performing so you should strive to write at as high level as possible before trying optimizations.

Also there is `Data.Sequence` which I think will perform better than `Array` while keeping you away from `ST` monad.

A useful typeclass instance to implement is `Traversable`. It is also cumbersome to implement as `innerArray` approach will work poorly:

```
instance Traversable FixedLengthQueue where
    traverse f = fmap fromArray . traverse f . innerArray where
        fromArray a = FLQ (rangeSize $ bounds a) 0 a
```

Interestingly, `Prelude` uses "innerList" approach - it converts an array to a list and back:

```
instance Ix i => Traversable (Array i) where
        traverse f arr = listArray (bounds arr) `fmap` traverse f (elems arr)
```

So I think the best we can do with `Traversable` is to use "innerList" approach too:

```
instance Traversable FixedLengthQueue where
    traverse f = fmap (fromJust . fromList) . traverse f . toList
```

Here is an `Eq` instance:

```
instance (Eq a) => Eq (FixedLengthQueue a) where
    (FLQ l1 _ _) == (FLQ l2 _ _) | l1 /= l2 = False
    q1 == q2 = toList q1 == toList q2
```

Here is another approach to implement `toList`:

```
indexList p l = range (p, l - 1) ++ range (0, p - 1)

toList' (FLQ l p a) = map (a !) $ indexList p l
```

I'm not sure that it's much better though, but the idea can be used everywhere:

```
eq (FLQ l1 p1 a1) (FLQ l2 p2 a2) = l1 == l2 && comp where
    r1 = indexList p1 l1
    r2 = indexList p2 l2
    comp = Prelude.all (\(i1, i2) -> (a1 ! i1) == (a2 ! i2)) $ zip r1 r2
```

Comment: `foldl' inc 0 xs` is necessary to avoid name conflicts with `Prelude.length`.

Comment: Just use qualified `Prelude.length` name :)

Comment: **Thanks** for all the *wonderful* feedback! I'm going to wait a few days before accepting the answer in the hope that it being unaccepted might attract another reviewer.